# Ramification of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2},p^{1/p})$

Tags: number-theory, local-field

I am interested in the extension of local fields $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2},p^{1/p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$. Is it totally ramified?

Here are the partial results that I have:

1. It is a field extension of degree $p^2(p-1)$. To see that, note that it suffices to show $p^{1/p} \not \in \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})$. Indeed, otherwise $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p}) \subset \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})$, thus $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is an abelian extension, hence contains its conjugate $\zeta_p \cdot p^{1/p}$, hence also contains $\zeta_p$, which is of degree $p-1$ a contradiction.
2. It's Galois group is an explicite group of order $p^{2}(p-1)$, its element its uniquely determined by its action on $\zeta_{p^2}$ and $p^{1/p}$.
3. Its ramification index is at least $p(p-1)$, indeed, $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is a totally ramified extension of degree $p(p-1)$

But I can not figure out whether it has chance to have an unramified subextension.

Comment: I have an argument that the extension is still totally ramified, but it uses higher ramification theory, and can’t possibly be the easiest proof available. Very likely someone slicker than me can give a better; if you don’t get one in several days, come back to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you’re taking a $p$-th root of $p$ in $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2})$, a local field that contains all the $p$-th roots of unity. Let $L=K(p^{1/p})$, it has degree $p$ over $K$.

As $K$ is totally ramified over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $L$ is totally ramified over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $L/K$ is totally ramified. Suppose (for the sake of contradiction) that it is false.

Then $L/K$ is unramified of degree $p$, and thus contained in a cyclotomic extension. Therefore $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension, and again we find a contradiction as $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p})$ is not Galois.

Comment: Cool answer! And it generalized to $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n},p^{1/p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ for any $n$!